# Should we have chat events, and if so, how should we do them?

Tags: discussion, chat, chat-events

Chat events recently came up in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57676167#57676167). If we are to have events, it would be a good idea to plan out the following things first:

- What the events will be about
- How often they'll be
- Whether we'll hold them in the Nineteenth Byte or a separate chat room.

It'd be great to get suggestions on the above topics, so could you guys answer with one or more proposals for the above points, or whether or not we should have chat events at all?

Answer (score 10):

## Monthly Mini Golf in The Nineteenth Byte

Every month, we could hold an event in TNB which lasts an hour or two. CMCs could be drafted ahead of time (or during the event), and through some method we could choose which ones are posted when (or just make it a free for all).

We could optionally also have some sort of scoring, where the person who wins the most CMCs would be the winner and potentially get a bounty.

This would be a fun introduction for some users to TNB or even CGCC as a whole, and for users who are already active it could be a fun event to build the community.

I don't think the clutter would be too much of a concern; other sites have similar events in their main chat rooms, and this is about as on topic as we can get. The events feature would advertise the event a little ahead of time, and users could register for it (which isn't required, but notifies them when it's about to start).

Comment: Sounds good but what about weekly mini events and monthly 'main' ones?

Comment: @rak1507 What would differentiate them? I feel like they'd just sort of merge into weekly main ones, and that would be both more disruptive, and less of a "special occasion" sort of thing that brings in a ton of people to both the site and the chat room.

Comment: Good point, I just want as much golf as possible :P

Comment: What hour or two? We have people from a large variety of timezones - It would make more sense to have it last a whole day. Good idea though!

Comment: @Ausername A day-long event would get pretty tiring to manage, and I'm not even sure if they can be scheduled for that long. We can maybe shift around the time every month, or try to optimize it so that the most people possible are awake.

Comment: For reference, for each new Project Euler problem released, the release time shifts by 8 hours. I guess we can use a similar model for the event.

Answer (score 7):

## Yes

This is a good way to introduce our community. It may not be as effective as the Hot Network Questions (for example), but if anyone happens to be on SE Chat accross the network, they will be more likely to see the Nineteenth Byte (and hopefully join CGCC).

### An event idea: Esolang Showcase

While on main "challenges that require the answers to be in a specific language are generally discouraged", in an esolang showcase event chatters could solve simple challenges like "Hello World" or "Fizz Buzz" in a predetermined language someone wishes to share.

Answer (score -1):

## Yes, advertised in TNB, held elsewhere

As I [said in TNB](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240/2021/4/16/23-24), my biggest worry about having scheduled events is that it could disrupt on-topic conversations held by people who don't want to be part of the event. It'd be unfair to force them to stop discussing whatever they are discussing, and it's impractical to hold a conversation in the middle of an event.

Therefore, I suggest that we schedule events in TNB's schedule, thus advertising them more, and then, when the event begins, users who want to take part move into a secondary room, and we keep a temporary pin to direct any late arrivals to the appropriate place.

Comment: IMO a golfing competition is the _most_ on topic thing that could take place in TNB. An hour or two of disruption isn't that significant, and we get similar disruption every day during things like AoC when that's almost the entire conversation every day for a while after it starts. Other sites' main chat rooms do similar things quite often, and have for years, which seems to be evidence that they aren't overly large burdens on the site or chat room. There's really very little point in making it a TNB event if it's just a redirect to another chat room.