# Introducing Biweekly Mini Golf!

Tags: discussion, chat, chat-events

In order to grow our community and its chat room, [The Nineteenth Byte](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte), we decided [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22119/should-we-have-chat-events-and-if-so-how-should-we-do-them) to start a new <s>monthly</s> **biweekly** chat event: Biweekly Mini Golf!

During this event, a number of previously drafted "CMCs" (short for Chat Mini Challenge) will be posted, and anyone can reply with their solutions. It will last between one and two hours, and users can register for the event beforehand.

**How will it work?**

For a little while before the event is scheduled, we'll host an unofficial CMC drafting workshop. These CMCs will be short and simple, and the rules for answers won't be quite as strict.

At the start of the event, some of these CMCs will be posted, and additional ones can be added during the event. Anyone can post their solutions (and golfs), and ROs will be around to help new users and keep discussion from straying too far off topic.

**When will it take place?**

The first Biweekly Mini Golf was on **Tuesday, May 11th** at 00:00 UTC (20:00 on Monday in EST).

<s>We will rotate between Tuesdays and Thursdays, and shift the start time in 8 hour increments. We [will now rotate](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/23757/66833) between 00:00UTC and 12:00UTC on Wednesdays. [Register yourself here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/240/the-nineteenth-byte?tab=schedule)</s>

**See you there!**

#### Biweekly Mini Golf has now been [discontinued](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/24821/66833) as of the 15th of June, 2022