# Chat Event: Learn-a-lang

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, chat, chat-events

### Advertisement

Been pushing off learning that one lang for too long? Maybe it doesn't qualify for LotM status? Then [name pending] is for you!

This is perfect for languages which are too popular for LotM, or which have already been done a while back. But we're not discriminating, bring your fave lang along!

- Maybe it's *Jelly*, *Retina*, *J* or *APL* that you haven't gotten around to, but those are too popular for LotM.
- Maybe a 'legacy' language like *05AB1E* or *GolfScript*.
- Maybe you missed the LotM entry or want more practice for *Vyxal* & *Brachylog*.
- Maybe you want to get better at golfing in a mainstream lang like *Python* or *C*.
- Maybe it's a just not general purpose enough for LotM. Think *`///`*, *Befunge*, *Canvas*, *Piet*. The event's problems will be tailored to that lang!

Any which way, we've got you covered!

### Inspiration

This is based off @cairdcoinheringaahing's CMC [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58764504#58764504):

> In a language you've never used before, calculate the n triangular number

We started discussing how to make this a recurring thing in the TNB [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58765023#58765023).

### Basics

The general idea right now is to have an event where we're all doing CMC's in a pre-decided language.

If someone volunteers to teach it, there can also be a primer for X minutes before it officially starts. Or they can just be fielding preliminary questions or sharing golfing tips.

### Discuss

- We chatted about this in TNB & it had some support there. Is this something the rest of the site would want to do?
- Should we prioritize languages which aren't eligible for LotM (again)?
- [What should we call it?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/23739) We'll vote on the name based on the ideas here once this thread stabilizes.
- What format should the event take? Will it be:

  - problem-based, like BMG
  - tutorial-based, like APL cultivation
  - long-term, like LotM for a week
- If the language already has its own room, do we use its room, or do we use a separate room for this event? (or do we use TNB)?
- Which room do we use?

  - Lang-specific, if it exists
  - Event-specific: make a room for [name pending]
  - General: TNB
- How often?

  - Weekly
  - Biweekly
  - Monthly

**Credits:** Thanks to [@cairdcoingheringaahing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66833/caird-coinheringaahing) for the inspiration and feedback on the draft. Thanks to [@user](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95792/user) for helping me write this up. Thanks to [@DLosc](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16766/dlosc) for choosing the post name. And thanks to everyone else in TNB for riding along!

Answer (score 8):

I think this is a good idea, and would like to see it become an event that happened somewhat regularly in TNB.

I'd imagine this in a similar format to our [Biweekly Mini Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22276/66833). Leading up to the event, languages would be nominated by participants, then voted on (stars in a non-TNB room) to determine which lang is used. I disagree with the idea of prioritising certain languages, and I'm not sure whether or not to allow languages to be duplicated in this event.

During the event, users who are more familiar with the language help those less familiar. This could be through a primer, as [suggested by Avi](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58765072#58765072), or just by answering questions. One key thing: these users should not be expected to be *teachers*, just as those more familiar. Anyone who wants to can post CMCs (typically trivial CMCs), ask questions about the language and otherwise discuss it.

I'm not entirely sure what timescale this would be best on, but every two weeks (likely staggered with BMG) seems like it would be a good idea. I have no strong opinions on the name of the event.

Comment: BMG kinda died.

Answer (score 2):

## Name Ideas

### Format

*Ideas are grouped by 'family' to make voting simpler later.*

Include any variations in stylization, except 'lang' vs. 'language' and capitalization; we'll decide on that last. For now everything should use 'lang' and title caps to standardize the options.

### Ideas

- **Learn a Lang**

  - Learn'a lang
  - Learn-a-lang
  - Learnalang
  - Learn a lang
- **Lang of the Week**

  - Lang of the Week
  - Language of the Week
  - Lang of the Weak
  - Lang of the Fortnight (if biweekly)
- **Learn You a Lang for Great Good**

  - Learn You a New Lang for Great Good
  - Learn You a Lang for Great Good
- **Try a Language**

Answer (score 1):

I'd be delighted if such an event happens. Here are some of my opinions, if that's alright:

- We chatted about this in TNB & it had some support there. Is this something the rest of the site would want to do?

It's likely something many users would want to participate in. Learning new languages is fun!

- Should we prioritize languages which aren't eligible for LotM (again)?

No. I don't like the idea of prioritizing previous LotM nominations at all, and prioritizing languages that are too popular for LotM doesn't make sense, as we also want to promote less commonly used esolangs.

- What format should the event take?

I think it should be a long-term thing like LotM (but for a week). If someone's willing, tutorials in addition to that would be great, but that's not always possible.

- Which room do we use?

I think we should <s>make a separate room just for this event</s> use TNB where people can post CMCs, CMC answers, and questions involved with the language for that week.

- How often?

Weekly seems the best option to me. It's not so long that people will have to wait a long time for their favorite language to show up, and a week is enough time to learn the basics of a language and decide if you like it or not.

Comment: A week-long event, combined with being in a non-TNB room, sounds like a guarantee that this would die out quickly. For better or worse, chat has a short, focusssed attention span, and so long term events, or non-TNB rooms are very easy to die out

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing You're right, and it probably won't cause *too much* clutter in TNB.