# Should we let Vyxal Bot into TNB when Vyxal is the LYAL

Tags: discussion, chat, chat-events

**Context**: Given that Vyxal is roughly under a month away from being selected for LYAL (at the time of posting, my calculations place it as being 1-2 LYALs away), I figured I'd write this so it can garner feedback and hopefully approval in time.

Over in [the Vyxal chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106764/vyxal), we have a neat little bot called [Vyxal Bot](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/71629/vyxal-bot) that does all sorts of cool things like post github events (e.g PRs, issues and so on), allow for funny moments in chat ([example](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59918059#59918059)) and other stuff. These commands obviously are off-topic for TNB in general, and they would be disabled during LYAL.

The command that would remain active is `!!/run` - this allows you to run Vyxal Code from chat messages, something that would be helpful during the Vyxal LYAL when it happens:

[image: Example of the run command]

[hyper-neutrino has previously mentioned they'd be able to write a minimised version of the bot that makes sure only the `!!/run` command can be used](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=59819265#59819265), so there wouldn't be any chance of abuse of other commands. The only problem could be the initial wave of people mucking around with the run command to figure out how it works, as well as people potentially spamming commands. However, those could just be moved to the bakery or trash.

The bot would remain in the room for the duration of the LYAL event, which IIRC is a maximum of 24 hours, so it'd be back in the Vyxal chat after the learning finished (we need it for our own purposes after all lol).

So what do y'all think? Vyxal Bot in TNB for Vyxal LYAL when it happens?

Comment: What is LYAL? Also TNB.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro [LYAL](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/23771/66833) stands for "Learn You A Lang", short for "Learn You A Lang For Great Good". TNB is [The Nineteenth Byte](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte), the main chatroom for the site

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So long as the bot is only in the room during the event, and that it only speaks when spoken to<sup>*</sup>, I think having the bot will be a useful resource for the LYAL event, and should be let into the room.

<sup>*</sup>Note that I'm not restricting it to only `!!/run`, only to commands that require someone to ping the bot specifically to get it to chat. For example, if the bot has any commands that provide documentation for a given Vyxal command, those would also be helpful during the event, so should be allowed. If this results in noise, the fault isn't entirely on the bot, and we can ask the users making the noise to stop and trash the messages if need be.