# Language of the Month for August 2022: Knight

Tags: discussion, language-of-the-month

In accordance with [our meta agreement](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19271/reviving-language-of-the-month-pick-up-where-we-left-off-or-start-over), since one candidate received more votes than the others, we have a new featured language! Throughout August 2022, our Language of the Month will be:

> ## Knight

### What's a Language of the Month?

See the [meta post for nominations](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19279/nominations-for-language-of-the-month-take-2?answertab=scoredesc#tab-top). In short, during August, those who wish to participate should learn (at least the basics of) Knight, and use it to solve challenges. Participation is completely optional, but is anticipated to be fun!

### Information about Knight

Knight is a new programming language created in April 2021 by sampersand. It is a Polish notation language (meaning `x + y` is `+ x y`, and everything has fixed arity) which is relatively simple. It has some useful string manipulation tools, eval, shell commands, and type coercion.

#### Interpreters

There is a list of interpreters on the [official GitHub page](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang). It has been ported to many languages, even itself.

[Here is an interpreter on TIO](https://tio.run/##rVltV9vKEf5s/4rFOVhaWU5kQc@5x7bMIbmQckogF5LmA7hByDLoVJZdSYZLCf3r6czsi1Z@SZv28sGydp@ZnXl2dmbWRN27KPr@KsmidDmJh0U5Seav70dNcyRNbmtDUfm0iFdAeZLd1YbKZCYwk3iaZDFLU5bOszv6aOrRT2efP7Be9Xr56YL51etfDy/YfvV6fPaO/VK9XnxmvQp8fHppYM8@nxrQz2cfDi//Yhec2fjRZv/q/Ynr2cNLWFZMRvdhzhxeCZgosFWrGI3YfjV3dvQFJzOYJI@@Mfw@HK5gcBnCoJuASVOOwBrm7fn5KYHw44Cc7KNvhiEX7wUA5A1bH8J0GXN@lY15s0l@wK5cjYOL1tH5sf39vPXnOE3nLvsyz9PJTus7h@HWQCAdgMbhjAUoM2g2QfEizIvY5uy52UiykiWDZgNGaRGXOdNlFsEICUfwXs4WbrHIrvxx8Oy53gvoaCSgjvDw9HDgzRtUnyzY431SxsUijOJmA76nsQ3jIG4LM1zWui6vs@vpdc6eX67GNu@/anEypZFMma2tDZj1yuJMqFCjOzB6ncFwpyNGwM5GnBaxOfAizInu4@jvbDrPWbac3cZ5Ie1hdlJMkrukVFphdXSn52qPxNNhPY91mCMt73Q46zLLs2AJtDThLI/LZZ4xFRZCjCJjsGrDQ5gn4W0aKyvAiHT@GOd2BOspQ9i3b0wZF9FbRER8tbikJ9ngehL0XNijQA@vWIcHTQYkQLLJcmHjljLJaZfB27rB4tgXQpsw49qyKptaltg0EAYPtFEMlECagO9g2SIsSlbex6AszEsAyw1wFKO4oRFHT5SxxunZaix89jhtdKMig8zH0C2TeQZmY8R6YzAtUowUy8UCCecqqtSISb8Zf0C7QTbqUKG8yCCOIWVh5ErLBSufLH2uxcAxDmD66mPaQjNVkFHGE67aaDeaGsIpjux9z@1xdBCHtRPkYLZM0zB/Mh2t9ufC2J6PlraMFpTyy2xFmpbo4RIyKWzy9PDo7bub33ZOfz03HDbV3iYb9frrendqit@fXG7RWMY5qQyzCfvHMlSvqPbBXGJvfQlBwHtLc3GygQsS3q8L1zEvlCrzZYY7NJBp1ynnha1yJR0ACO0yiRjN3i6nV/7@WNohNrpN6UEbUCzgWJVTG6Dg/26aTloq71DZcVHJqgI4FFqBKGhi/RpuyHp7dT/ReYzFA9Yq82XcghjU4xiSMD4NIYPgRAsjq1WRgH6i77LyEB1f387nKczc1hnY6mvl1o8ccn7eI9PM2zUzU7Qx@0NthKAt52lqm6a6zHOhQvwPJmdrJmMV/nD48czFWiwCDV5Prnqe50E4gSvwqt6K5J/x15LhY2DEqOEtMgBvLn749LkX9FRJxwyHVR0f9OmLxx4Ajk9Ojxw2heQ4aOjQluthGo7ChZvGGXUABleqMRKcwbnbRsaqINYmLG1YcOyEegmoxUPiYgBFJcFJnTei2WJlB4ikZFylEKQpGeMyxWNSRve2A8ys9VHAEZN/EdYp69DqM1xFAAIkFDsxyMK8TU5J9bIXrIUsH1AVrhDUcJY5li7qOa/G/LkKM2igKLeLhS9g4bruHDKezdve71P8q5AfAQlaBUd3cZlCu2i3aS/buENYIidJxgfJ1LZpP7EhiO5ztMWFOOVcbHPgDTbaCg9ObYBY70isJzpHzAaSkIGyF0mSubOy8m3lj8DrmXfVDEqaFGvMDWAwGiD@gsV8EWe2sbDbylvUKoBVwUxUSojHwPf2f6Fx2VzYoiOZgukTdApaOAhZF/s7gEPvQG@4BiytwsuGQdYJqBXCEwtILukGPbQWUY0anID5Zs9S0Vh58ht4Ev8ObRye9jU/d2q7TreCHcxka8DTtfCAVdI6Lwb8V6sv@8QNgawzn6xArTNqi22sQVwVodFon1eN5Vo6VKKX1BzauwUK1g/DujDQCa2PuS5kUt6qoGoCy0scZlLtthIma5a5AzK3SBbOKxbwYIiLD5Im9rNGHWu36SrV7SJ0LNrca2q3G8qs3ddOAfbY8MaZOmq5Yf6yLNTu65gQvZ4wqKMNojwJ@RJTMoaWsT2im27Ud1vcSxENfT9TseSLPcf@lw6D2ABC4TCe8kB56fPNoRqFpXrIrrPXqWji6jvq4tCNuvQsZY6QfnXXotOIdmzV6/YKIafanQ0srJbnDTw4azyIfd3EwmyDaw5hAlMJCUANsilDBtY1XPIQNOh2SZ8kikrm6kYLRsva6X/zQ2LebCZm94dCu5uF/kZs1hwSVwca800vB5J2wXrAuj3NMmGB@h6cs24PzljPBPs/iR5CeqxhgwChtG5fjXiKciLaH3mSa59Tu@IExH9z9UDQJLkCdwRKsFhi4DteGe7jPLYKls2hh07SMsnYY/gEvLHJHO6kZXwX5yCzmGdxViYh3iLgJM/ZY8zuw4cYgFIRwks2C7MlhM/TaxxF726RcaCCmCiWaYk/GtDiOuEpSNfEqCVXKDPlNGRFPerbjvS2G6JhwxrKo/t5mGJtfAKvs0kaT9hNZfaN1vKM30RjZixSOTNCZd2ueucEb0ioY5j@ovPgkIJ1pfBh0qvlxaCeFQ@YefiH5jFA0b78xa3NBOCA1RpFGnSZkQ1RhyckVcn1RR1A7E4A1cbogkZwKDG05pN5n83iWbTAMMvY6Obg/3Vl9Ae4MlKu7GzwJZC@SFcOtrMvVt1gMk4fsBrA1whfFdCdTXZWL9o9lXlMBdq8dpX@0JdNteHAlJSpRMt/@2/kZQ4y1Gj5gdU30bU2dxUbVFm3Pv3TFxnV21Y3GcQ1arcZnQoJgxrHQU3aSJMogYhOR4sJk7@Ae@JXL7PRrHnHzN5Fip3Uu3aEGvIHfn/PoOW9uDIERofVMQvQ@h0pkxcPV5@FvVpDeymIXlE6WC15/qaSt8d1H@Br6X0a/A8NERqGT9yKSDf/uh0yeyMfPMRVOz1skqhBEPEvJulBiI48CbD6JJ6GkCTBM9VhJhlMJhP6ESmMSihT1m5kYc@JI5xtucWiMl0DoRuUPyTMwiTDZpWF@V3kklLHge8PHH@uovsl/gPH9sia@jXu5fu/AQ), a patch to a previous commit to [c/golf](https://github.com/knight-lang/c/tree/master/golf) which updates and fixes some conformance issues. (Note that it memory leaks like crazy and segfaults on malformed inputs).

However, the "preferred" interpreter is [c/ast](https://github.com/knight-lang/c/tree/master/ast), which is the fastest, most up-to-date interpreter and has actual error checking.

**EDIT:** I (Steffan) put a JS interpreter on TIO [here](https://tio.run/##lVjZcts2FH3vV9BsahESTcuZTjsWTXsS12kzbeQ0dptpJSUCQUhiQhEKF9upxP56ei@4gdqc5iEjAgd3w7kL/IHe0ZhF/iI5CoXHv7CAxrH2a@hPZ8lVFIlI4w8JD71Yk1/LLAe8plHMm/vKmRL1Jg0Tf/447iaJOJ0vmQjjJEpZIiKDkmUy82MrFmnEuEMz2PEXb2d@wuMFZdwo9uc0YTPj@J0xGI6Gg2EM61lv1Fl9O3g3DEdtYxiunhDSPibZgvOPsBvxJI1CTRE@6I5WqzANgiwX5prM6ZJlwBONOq7FHzgzFDixCxF4xHEceoE/eirEUX5bceqC7QYFNVbAw2kyIyYdsBHJEgGO@@F0q1VZJsOh3f71@urGGYzsPFR/0iDlyzihic@0Bd6C4ZKla22Ex55AFO9oBD50bXomxRT6bdrp5P4xR64P6MgqZdn@xGCksIdliq9ZlIYy7JG410J@nzMi87ibTres7/BOCrHqTcD107nLox24chNwz4UIOA13AKvdrGDVbxCMiAYV8fLQrZEsThco3ZSi3ns0ocC13FFFyRZniu/63DZPiu8maMO). It's from the [JS implementation on GitHub](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight.js), but compiled into one file. Note: When putting input into the program, make sure to put a trailing newline. Otherwise, it will infinitely loop, unfortunately.

### Resources

- [Main GitHub](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang) (has spec, test suite, examples)
- [Official spec](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang/blob/master/specs.md)
- [Official Discord](https://discord.gg/A7RVbhMYFC)
- [Esolangs.org entry](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Knight)
- [SE Chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138265/knight)

I (Steffan) will also offer a +100 bounty for any user's 3rd Knight answer in August.

Answer (score 5):

## List of all Knight answers posted in August 2022

- [Encode the alphabet cipher](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/97859/encode-the-alphabet-cipher/250600#250600) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [Encode the alphabet cipher](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251093/104135) by [Sampersand](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/104135/sampersand)
- [Shifted auto-sum](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/250338/shifted-auto-sum/250602#250602) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [Product over a range](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/66202/product-over-a-range/250606#250606) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [Transform characters of your choice into "Hello, world!"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/250556/transform-characters-of-your-choice-into-hello-world/250611#250611) by [Adam](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/113573/adam)
- [Repeat Hello World according to another string's length](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/250516/repeat-hello-world-according-to-another-strings-length/250612#250612) by [Adam](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/113573/adam)
- [Sum of all integers from 1 to n](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/133109/sum-of-all-integers-from-1-to-n/250613#250613) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [The vanilla factorial challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250619/78410) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [The vanilla factorial challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250620/78410) by [Bubbler](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler)
- [Write a Deadfish Interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/218260/write-a-deadfish-interpreter/250621#250621) by [Adam](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/113573/adam)
- ["Hello, World!"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55422/hello-world/250622#250622) by [Adam](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/113573/adam)
- [Print a 10 by 10 grid of asterisks](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250623/78410) by [Bubbler](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler)
- [Determine whether strings are anagrams](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250626/78410) by [Bubbler](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler)
- [Determine whether strings are anagrams](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251096/104135) by [Sampersand](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/104135/sampersand)
- [Print the last, middle and first character of your code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250635/78410) by [Bubbler](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler)
- [Sums of Consecutive Integers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/66193/sums-of-consecutive-integers/250640#250640) by [Adam](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/113573/adam)
- [Determine whether strings are anagrams](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1294/determine-whether-strings-are-anagrams/250647#250647) by [DLosc](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/16766/dlosc)
- [Reverse hex cipher](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/247804/reverse-hex-cipher/250651#250651) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [Multiply numbers by their depth](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/250242/multiply-numbers-by-their-depth/250652#250652) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [Reverse hex cipher](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250658/78410) by [Bubbler](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler)
- [Shortest code to produce non-deterministic output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/101638/shortest-code-to-produce-non-deterministic-output/250660#250660) by [Bubbler](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler)
- [Does the start equal the end?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250665/78410) by [Bubbler](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler)
- [Triangle area from side lengths](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/250447/triangle-area-from-side-lengths) by [Adam](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/113573/adam)
- ["Multiply" two strings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/125470/multiply-two-strings/250681#250681) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [Calculate average characters of string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/53675/calculate-average-characters-of-string/250682#250682) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [Erverse Hte Ifrst Wto Eltters fo Aech Owrd](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/249523/erverse-hte-ifrst-wto-eltters-fo-aech-owrd/250684#250684) by [Adam](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/113573/adam)
- [Determine whether strings are anagrams](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1294/determine-whether-strings-are-anagrams/250686#250686) by [Adam](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/113573/adam)
- [Shortest code to produce non-deterministic output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/101638/shortest-code-to-produce-non-deterministic-output/250693#250693) by [Adam](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/113573/adam)
- [Is this a triangle?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/199353/is-this-a-triangle/250692#250692) by [Adam](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/113573/adam)
- [Summation from a to b](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/60106/summation-from-a-to-b/250695#250695) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [Strange Addition](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/176010/strange-addition/250696#250696) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [Additive Persistence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1775/additive-persistence/250697#250697) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [It's Hip to be Square](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/125237/its-hip-to-be-square/250710#250710) by [Adam](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/113573/adam)
- [Print an alphabet wave](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/89283/print-an-alphabet-wave/250713#250713) by [Adam](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/113573/adam)
- [Construct the Identity Matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/70365/construct-the-identity-matrix/250721#250721) by [Adam](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/113573/adam)
- [Shortest infinite loop producing no output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/59347/shortest-infinite-loop-producing-no-output/250722#250722) by [Adam](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/113573/adam)
- [Find ranges of True values in a list](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69156/find-ranges-of-true-values-in-a-list/250753#250753) by [Jonah](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/15469/jonah)
- [Trick or Treat polyglot](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/97472/trick-or-treat-polyglot/250755#250755) by [Jonah](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/15469/jonah)
- [Cryptic Multiplications](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/250745/cryptic-multiplications/250757#250757) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [Backronymiser឵឵](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/249788/backronymiser/250758#250758) by [Jonah](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/15469/jonah)
- [Swap every two elements in a list](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/237085/swap-every-two-elements-in-a-list/250759#250759) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [Lolololololololololololol](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/210976/lolololololololololololol/250760#250760) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [Count up forever](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/63834/count-up-forever/250761#250761) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [Shortest code to produce infinite output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/13152/shortest-code-to-produce-infinite-output/250762#250762) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [Print 0 to 100 without 1-9 characters](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/219576/print-0-to-100-without-1-9-characters/250767#250767) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [Print A-Z and their alphabet index without using 1,2,4,6](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/219945/print-a-z-and-their-alphabet-index-without-using-1-2-4-6/250771#250771) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [1, 2, miss a few, 99, 100](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/219495/1-2-miss-a-few-99-100/250772#250772) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [Triangular code, triangular output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/203062/triangular-code-triangular-output/250773#250773) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [Hello ASCII World!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/201650/hello-ascii-world/250774#250774) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [Print the ASCII Code page](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/249247/print-the-ascii-code-page/250794#250794) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [Print the ASCII printable character set](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/85088/print-the-ascii-printable-character-set/250795#250795) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [Implement String Projection](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/250781/implement-string-projection/250801#250801) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [Pairs at every distance](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/249384/pairs-at-every-distance/250854#250854) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [Anti-divisors of a number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/250883/anti-divisors-of-a-number/250897#250897) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [Implement an Over function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/223881/implement-an-over-function/250934#250934) by [Adam](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/113573/adam)
- [Divisor of a string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/250942/divisor-of-a-string/250961#250961) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [A better Hexagony template](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/251002/a-better-hexagony-template/251035#251035) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [Could you make me a hexagon please?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/104604/could-you-make-me-a-hexagon-please/251039#251039) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [Unfolding the Hexagony source code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/66708/unfolding-the-hexagony-source-code/251044#251044) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [I reverse the source code, you negate the input!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/193021/i-reverse-the-source-code-you-negate-the-input/251047#251047) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [I reverse the source code, you negate the output!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/192979/i-reverse-the-source-code-you-negate-the-output/251048#251048) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [Smallest subset of characters required for Turing Completeness](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/247536/smallest-subset-of-characters-required-for-turing-completeness/251069#251069) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [Fewest (distinct) characters for Turing Completeness](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/110648/fewest-distinct-characters-for-turing-completeness/251072#251072) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [Numbers with Rotational Symmetry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77866/numbers-with-rotational-symmetry/251098#251098) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [A challenge for rookies](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/251101/a-challenge-for-rookies/251119#251119) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [smallest number of steps for a knight in chess](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/251050/smallest-number-of-steps-for-a-knight-in-chess/251122#251122) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [Prime Challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/209805/prime-challenge/251128#251128) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [Repeated! Factorials!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/189240/repeated-factorials/251141#251141) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [Covfefify a string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/123685/covfefify-a-string/251074#251074) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [Print/Output the L-phabet](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/87064/print-output-the-l-phabet/251184#251184) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [I'm a palindrome. Are you?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/110582/im-a-palindrome-are-you/251185#251185) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [Ot wes thi bist uf tomis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/163141/ot-wes-thi-bist-uf-tomis/251203#251203) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [Collatz Conjecture (OEIS A006577)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12177/collatz-conjecture-oeis-a006577/251225#251225) by [Adam](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/113573/adam)
- [Write a program to elasticize strings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/83377/write-a-program-to-elasticize-strings/251231#251231) by [Sampersand](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/104135/sampersand)
- [Find an Illegal String](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/133486/find-an-illegal-string/251232#251232) by [Sampersand](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/104135/sampersand)
- [Stretch the word](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77043/stretch-the-word/251247#251247) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [Code-Golf: Permutations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5056/code-golf-permutations/251253#251253) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [Exploded Suffixes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/96271/exploded-suffixes/251263#251263) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [Interleave strings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/102496/interleave-strings/251303#251303) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [Carry-less sum given a base b](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/251283/carry-less-sum-given-a-base-b/251309#251309) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [Output your Score!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/160646/output-your-score/251323#251323) by [Benji](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/91473/benji)
- [Find the number of integers in the range from 1 to N that ends with 2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/200363/find-the-number-of-integers-in-the-range-from-1-to-n-that-ends-with-2/251320#251320) by [Benji](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/91473/benji)
- [Radiation Hardening KOTH](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/251161/radiation-hardening-koth/251317#251317) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [Am I divisible by double the sum of my digits?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/129596/am-i-divisible-by-double-the-sum-of-my-digits/251328#251328) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [Dad jokes are fun](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/185872/dad-jokes-are-fun/251350#251350) by [Benji](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/91473/benji)
- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<challenge title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

## List of relevant tips posted in August 2022

- [Shorten functions to single characters](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250778/113573) by [Adam](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/113573/adam)
- [Remove spaces between variables and functions, rearrange parameters so that a number comes first](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250765/113573) by [Adam](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/113573/adam)
- [Use output of assignment to chain assignments](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250764/113573) by [Adam](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/113573/adam)
- [Use `ASCII` and `GET` to iterate through strings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250765/113573) by [Adam](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/113573/adam)
- [Use coercion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250792/92689) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)
- [Use `T`/`F` instead of `1`/`0`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251090/104135) by [Sampersand](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/104135/sampersand)
- [Use `&` and `|` instead of `I`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251091/104135) by [Sampersand](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/104135/sampersand)
- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<tip summary>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

## List of relevant challenges posted in August 2022

- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<challenge title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```