# Do we want to delete a LYAL nomination after learning the lang?

Tags: discussion, chat-events

Currently, [Language nominations for the "Learn You a Lang for Great Good" chat event](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/23771/16766), if they get chosen, are subsequently edited to mention that this language was learned on such-and-such a date. We've [brought up in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/61802801#61802801) the possibility of deleting old nominations, like we do for [Language of the Month nominations](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19279/16766). The idea seems to have support, but nobody has done much about it. So let's make an actual decision. **Should we delete old LYAL nominations that have already been learned (for great good)?** Why or why not?

Answer (score 12):

## Yes.

Currently, whenever looking for the next language, we have to scroll through all the previously learned ones. It's just annoying to search through and find the top-voted ones that haven't been done already.

Deleting learned languages would make this a lot easier.

Also, we're not losing any history - a list of all past LYALs can easily be obtained from TNB search, and the answers are still viewable to 10k+ users.

Comment: Or else, we can downvote the answers... But that's like way off the point