# Make each language's official [tips] page look more like the LYAL and LOTM templates?

Tags: discussion, tips

The nomination posts for [Learn You a Lang for Great Good](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/23771/16766) (LYAL) and [Language of the Month](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19279/16766) (LOTM) have a lot of good resources about most languages posted. This provides a very solid starting point for those wanting to learn to golf in some language. However, not every language can be nominated and I think it would be useful to have this information available for more languages, even those that would not be a good fit for LOTM.

The current template for a language's main [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) question seems to be something like this:

> Does anyone have tips on how to golf in this language? Please one tip per answer and avoid posting simple and general tips such as "remove whitespace".

I suggest something like this:

> Quick one sentence summary of the language
>
> ### Notable features
>
> - List of notable features, keep this very short, actual tips should be answers
>
> ### Resources
>
> - List of resources
>
> ### Where to run
>
> - List of notable online interpreters
>
> Does anyone have tips on how to golf in this language? Please one tip per answer and avoid posting simple and general tips such as "remove whitespace".

This way we'll have a nice central repository for resources on every language.

There would be no need to fill in every column when creating a [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) post, you can leave some of it empty for others to fill in. There could be extra sections added depending on the language too.

If you did not build the language yourself, I'd suggest making the post a community wiki.

Is this a good idea? Bad idea? If so, would it be acceptable to edit old [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) questions to fit this format?

Comment: Making the question a community wiki would make the answers wikis too, which is bad. Tips should be first class citizens, good tips deserve rewards.

Comment: I didn't know CW questions automatically made the answers CW

Answer (score 2):

## Good idea

"Tips for golfing in [language]" questions are a great place to go if you want to get better at golfing in a particular language. It makes sense to have links to other resources for that language in the same place.

### Keep it brief

The main point of a [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) question is to ask for tips; too much extraneous information is distracting. I'd say remove the "notable features" section. The most notable features should be part of the language summary.

### Shouldn't be mandatory

There's nothing wrong with asking a "tips for golfing in" question without putting links to other resources in the header. It's simply a bonus feature. I also don't see anything wrong with editing existing questions to include links to resources, but let's not do them all at once. Maybe one per week, or edit one if it's already on the active questions list because it got a new answer.

### Don't community wiki

As Radvylf pointed out in the comments, making a [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) question community wiki would force all the answers to be community wiki. This change would not be helpful; people should get reputation for good tips. It is unfortunate that reputation for the question itself goes to whoever thought of posting it first, but I'm not sure if there's a good way around that.