# Event Suggestion: Compression Golf

Tags: discussion

Most golfing languages that are competitive today use at least one string compression algorithm. My language Fig has a compressor that resembles Jelly's. I use been planning to add a super secret feature to it to make it better, however life got in the way.

Putting that aside, my failed attempt has made me wonder how compressed strings can get. Therefore, I propose <s>outsourcing my problem</s> creating an event where we can competitively write string compressors. I and one or two other judges will choose a few secret strings with which to test the compressors y'all submit. It may contain words, random sequences, repeating sequences, etc.      We will hive a hint as to their content before the event starts. Then, y'all will have a few weeks to write a string compressor. Then, the judges will test the compressors on all the strings, and the one with the best average compression ratio wins.

This is just a rough outline to get discussion started. I have already proposed this in chat with a few positive replies. The guidelines are intentionally vague, and *will* change if we decide to do this. What do y'all think?

Comment: Sounds fun! Yay!

Answer (score 11):

### Isn't this just a challenge?

As far as I can tell, this is less of an event, and more of just a [compression](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compression) challenge, akin to [this decade-old one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/4771/66833). Events, especially chat events, tend to be on-going things that can be repeated along a theme (see [Learn-a-lang](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23738/chat-event-learn-a-lang) or [BMG](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22276/introducing-biweekly-mini-golf)). This would just be a one-off thing over a couple of weeks or so - which is just a challenge.

As for judges, I feel that part is unnecessary as either an event or a challenge. Simply choose a few set strings beforehand, and share some hash of the strings that can be used to verify that the strings are identical when revealed after scoring

Comment: Hrm, why haven't I thought of that