# Biweekly Mini Golf is Half Dead

Tags: discussion, chat, chat-events

... **what should we do?**

As we can see from this excerpt, BMG is slowly dying. People don't seem interested enough to even start it and the 21st BMG has little participants.

> (even though it hasn't happened in months lol)

<sup>([Source](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/61265742#61265742))</sup>

I see the following problems and solutions:

#### Problem: People don't notice BMG.

- Solution: Make BMG more often. However this might make the audience have less interest in them.
- Solution: Make a room for it. However, "there doesn't need a million rooms for everything" and this makes things more complicated.

#### Problem: People don't like BMG.

- Solution: Make BMG less often. This might make the audience have more interest in them.
- Solution: Change BMG into something else. For instance, LYAL, or simply discard it. However CMCs probably seems interesting to many people like me and BMGs encourage CMCs.

### What do you think?

Answer (score 12):

### Let it die

BMG was [first started over a year ago](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22276/66833), was popular, [had a bit of a slump](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/23750/66833) after a couple of months, and, over the last 10 months has slowly died. And, *that's okay*.

If people aren't engaging with an event anymore, the proper thing to do is let it die. It was fun when it started, and that's great, but there's nothing wrong with saying "Well, the fun's over. What else should we do?"

Which brings me to the follow-up: if BMG is left to die, now what? Well, the obvious answer is: find another chat event to try! If you have an idea for an event, ask in chat if people would be interested, and, if there's support, post a proposal on [Meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chat-events) detailing the event.

Comment: Not to mention, anyone is still free to post CMCs anytime they like, and they frequently get a good response.