# Chat Event Proposal: Make You a Lang for Great Good

Tags: discussion, chat, chat-events

With the [demise](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/24821/107299) of BMG, I had an idea for a new chat event. For now, I'm calling it "Make You a Lang for Great Good", but that is beside the point. This event would focus on one of the largest aspects of the CGCC: language creation. Recently, there has been an influx of new languages being created, from rSN to flax to Vyxal 3 to Wellscripted. This chat event would encourage the creation and development of home-made languages. The developers will get to show off the features of the language, the other people can play around with it, and ideas can be spread. This might even accelerate the development of the first 4th generation golfing language. I have [proposed](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/61274007#61274007) this on chat, and got no negative comments, so here goes...

Comment: Do we have any ideas for a particular format? Not sure how strictly "formatted"/structured the event would have to be, but I worry if it is too vague it wont pick up the right kind of responses to keep it popular :?c Still, super excited for this!

Comment: @thejonymyster I don't have a definite format yet, this post is more of a proposal whether we should do it at all

Comment: @Seggan is it a time to create languages or try out newly-created languages? Your text seems to apply both: **This event would focus on one of the largest aspects of the CGCC: language creation** and **The developers will get to show off the features of the language**. Also, can you explain what a **4th generation golfing language** is?

Comment: If I had a nickel for each time there was a chat event that had an acronym close to something vyxal related, I'd have two nickels, which isn't a lot, but it's weird that it's happened twice.

Comment: @Nobody the point of this is not to *create* languages but to *work on/develop* them. Both sentences relate  to the same thing. As for golflang generations, 1st gen is golfscript/cjam, 2nd gen is jelly/pyth, 3rd gen is vyxal/osabie. The 4th generation is expected to come around sometime soon

Comment: Do you have any concrete ideas about how often it would take place? Also, great idea, looking forward to it!

Comment: @mathcat I̶ ̶h̶a̶v̶e̶ ̶s̶o̶m̶e̶ ̶i̶d̶e̶a̶ ̶o̶f̶ ̶h̶o̶w̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶w̶o̶u̶l̶d̶ ̶g̶o̶,̶ ̶i̶f̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶a̶p̶p̶r̶o̶v̶e̶d̶ ̶I̶ ̶w̶i̶l̶l̶ ̶l̶a̶y̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶o̶u̶t̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶a̶n̶o̶t̶h̶e̶r̶ ̶m̶e̶t̶a̶ ̶p̶o̶s̶t̶ misread your comment. I'd say biweekly to weekly

Comment: @Seggan nice. flyp i have to add more chars sry

Answer (score 14):

## Hell yes

If there's one thing I've noticed is hard to do well, it's asking other people for feedback on things like golfing language built-ins, syntax choices and language construction. Most times, messages requesting feedback just fall to the wayside, drowned out by either a) other conversations, or b) a lack of interest.

This event has the chance to help language developers get the help they need, as well as create community initiatives so that we as a generation of code golfers can come together and do cool stuff that future users will see and say "wow that's cool!". Ideally, MYAL would also accustom people to giving language design feedback outside of the event, eventually making the meta-game of code golf a prominent feature of site culture once again.

Comment: I keep on plugging (and antifreezing) [The Tarpit](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110136/the-tarpit), which exists for the purpose of esolang design feedback, but it doesn't get much attention. :(