# Chat Event Refinement: Make You a Lang for Great Good

Tags: discussion, chat, chat-events

[We have decided](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24826/107299) to make a chat event based on language creation. In this post, we will discuss *how* we should do it.

The event would just be a time dedicated to showing off WIP languages, get feedback on codepages/features/whatever from other people, and for those other people to just generally mess around and maybe learn a new golfing language.

### Time

It would go on for the whole day. However, this restriction will not apply in the event of the occurrence (certified by the United States Centers for Disease Control or successor body) of a widespread viral infection transmitted via bites or contact with bodily fluids that causes human corpses to reanimate and seek to consume living human flesh, blood, brain or nerve tissue and is likely to result in the fall of organized civilization.

### Name

For now, this is MYAL, Make You a Lang for Great Good, but we already have LYAL, and I'd like a different name.

*P.S. I've never written this kind of post so I may be missing a lot or have given useless info*

Comment: Idk, if organized civilization is falling apart I'd rather be on the team that has slightly more optimized golfing languages.

Comment: I'd rather have the event take place the whole day, that is starting from 0 UTC. (I might have misunderstood something)

Comment: @mathcat Yes, I planned to have it the whole day. Lemme refine it a bit

Comment: name suggestion: Untitled Lang Creation Event/Rally. 
aka ULCER

Comment: If the event is biweekly, it could be called Biweekly Assistance in Brilliantly Engineering Languages (BABEL) :P

Comment: I'd suggest you limit the scope of your *question* to describe what the post is for, and move your opinions into an answer, so people can vote on them separately.

Answer (score 14):

## Name proposal

While it doesn't make a clever acronym, **Language Design Workshop** would look very nice on the Upcoming Events list.

Comment: How is LaDeW? _

Comment: Personally, if I were to abbreviate it, I'd just go with LDW.

Comment: Okay then: LDW (pronounced Ladew. You *have* to pronounce it Ladew, otherwise organized civilizations will fall apart)

Answer (score 9):

## No hyperpings

These wouldn't be very useful, since:

- If you're already in the chat room, you don't need a ping
- If you're awake/online but not in chat, CGCC pings you on its own when the event is starting, so you can hop into chat
- If you're asleep/offline, you can just check the transcripts later, instead of either having to remember to remove your username from the list, or having a flooded inbox the next morning

Additionally, hosting this somewhere would create an external dependency that's baked into the event, which will cause problems.

Also, what would these pings be used for?

- Whenever the event starts? If so, chat does this already
- Whenever a new language is brought up? If so, we could just use a format like LYAL's **xMC:**, mabe **FR:** (feedback request), and you can search those on your own at any time
- Whenever you want feedback on a particular suggestion for a language? If so, that's a lot of pings, most of which will likely not be interesting to the majority of people. I might (and probably would) only want to provide feedback on certain languages, which would make the system far more complicated

Comment: But how many times have you seen someone ask for language feedback in TNB only to see it ignored and go by without visibility. Hyperpings allow for those interested in feature requests to be quickly alerted and makes enough of a statement to those who haven't already joined the ping list to see what's happening.

Comment: Also, CGCC pings you on its own when the event is starting, but not when it is in the middle.

Comment: @lyxal Well the point of this event is that interested people will already be in the room. Pinging them all is just unnecessary. Having an informal "ping me if you want feedback" thing would be fine, but baking it into the event creates a point of failure for the future.

Answer (score 4):

## Another Idea

### Name

I don't like MYAL that much, because it's too similar to LYAL.
I proposed DALC (Discuss About Language Creation) in the chat, but I don't like it much either.

### Hyperping

I don't like the idea of a bot being in the room biweekly/weekly.
I'd rather make a website where you can create ping lists and copy them when needed.

### Time & Room

I think creating another room would just be a clone of [The Tarpit](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110136/the-tarpit) and no one would probably participate in the event.
Maybe we could rotate between 00:00UTC and 12:00UTC as BMG did.

I do really hope organized civilizations won't fall apart.

Answer (score 4):

## Yet More Feedback

### Name

While I have nothing against MYAL as a name, perhaps something "non-acronym" like Community Directives or Community Initiatives could work.

### Hyperping

I suggested this, so I'm not really qualified to comment on it. But I will say that instead of having a separate bot, maybe it could be integrated into NSP/NMP. Or perhaps Vyxal Bot could be borrowed on MYAL days.

### Time

12am UTC to 12am UTC the next day would be best. Weekly is also a good idea. Don't have it rotate starting times, as that's just confusing.

Maybe have it on a Tuesday.

[image]

Tuesday looks active.

Comment: I would like separate bot like `<name of event> Bot` (because people may hyper ping all the time with NSP/NMP)

Comment: When you read this comment it'll be tuesday. Yes, I can read your mind. (Sorry I meant: I think tuesday's good)

Answer (score 4):

### Time

I'd like to have the event go for multiple days, so that people have a chance to get acquainted with the language so they can actually contribute to it before the event ends. However, we might start losing interest if it goes on too long, so I'd suggest 2-3 full days, probably starting and ending at 0:00 UTC.

Comment: I personally feel that if it lasts more than about 24-36 hours it might feel like its dragging on a bit too long

Answer (score 3):

## Time: 24 hours, with alternating start times

24 hours allows people to drop in throughout their day, no matter the timezone, but without dragging on so long that it starts to account for a large proportion of the week.

However, as we have experienced with LYAL, a lot of the time, the bulk of the activity tends to be immediately after the scheduled start time. So...

I suggest the start time alternate between 12AM and 12PM UTC, to allow that period of most activity to be accessible to people in varied timezones.

Answer (score 2):

## My Own Opinion (Copied from the Post)

Ideally, this should not be restricted to any one language at a time as LYAL is, but have anyone participate. If ideas are mixed around like this, it might lead to a new and improved generation of golfing languages. It also will probably make existing languages better.

One idea by @lyxal was to have a command that would only be allowed to run during the event, similar to the `!!/hyperping` command in the Vyxal chatroom, which a developer would use and a bot would ping all users interested in replying.

### Time

I would like this to happen weekly, preferably starting at a time convenient to me (i.e. 3 PM UTC or 12 AM UTC).

### Name

I really like @user's suggestion of BABEL, but since I don't think this should be done biweekly, it should be a recursive acronym: "BABEL: Assistance in Brilliantly Engineering Languages".

Answer (score 1):

## [esolangs.org](https://esolangs.org) category

I propose creating a category on the Esolang Wiki for languages spawned from or created during this event.

Comment: But this is for *developing* languages, not *creating* them...