# Chat Event Announcment: Language Development Workshop

Tags: discussion, chat, chat-events

BMG has died. Nearly immediately I [proposed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24826/chat-event-proposal-make-you-a-lang-for-great-good) the event that henceforth became known as MYAL. After a short [discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24835/chat-event-refinement-make-you-a-lang-for-great-good) to flesh out the details, and the chat event Language Development Workshop was born. Here, we will get to show off our languages and their features, chat about them, get feedback, try out WIP languages, and, hopefully, get to share ideas and perhaps accelerate the development of the first 4th generation golfing language.

It will be every other Wednesday at 12:00 UTC (8:00 EST), starting June 15th. Have fun!